# Can functions increase on critical points that are not turning points?

Tags: calculus, definition, interval-arithmetic

I am reading [this lecture](https://courseware.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/11/assignments/162/10). Therefore, I am asking the following question in terms of what the lecture states, and not in terms of what any other individual or group advocates, because I need to answer the assessment questions related to the lecture, and not personal opinions. (The reason I clarify this is that I am aware that a lot of things regarding definitions in math are debated, and this is a definition question.)

*According to the lecture whose link is provided above*, "a function is increasing on an interval $I$ if, for any pair of points, $x_1<x_2$ in $I$, $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$." Now, if I test every single pair of points on the graph $f(x)=x^3$, $x_1$ is always smaller than $x_2$, so the function is increasing on its entire domain, *as far as I understand*. Am I correct? If so, it is correct to say that $f(x)$ is increasing on $I(-1,1)$.

*However*, if you look at the [Answer](https://courseware.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/11/assignments/162/15) section for Question 1.b in the [Exercises](https://courseware.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/11/assignments/162/14) section (you can navigate to those sections using the sidebar), it is clear that $x=1$ is excluded from the list of points which can be used in pairs to test the statement above (that regarding the definition of increasing intervals). I feel like there is some sort of contradiction here, unless I am misinterpreting something in the lecture.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be a contradiction between the given answer and what the notes said. The notes specifically said that $x^3$ is increasing at $x=0$ despite the fact that the derivative is zero there.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for your comment. Oh, so it is a contradiction? That's a shame. Going away from my original question a bit, what would you say is the general agreement on increasing intervals containing critical points is, amongst the mathematical community?

Comment: I would consider the definition to be the one you gave, ending with "$f(x_1)<f(x_2)$." Having a positive derivative everywhere in the interval is sufficient but not necessary. I don't know if this is a consensus view, but it's the only one I know.

Comment: I agree with David K and would go further to say that this is *the* definition (i.e., there are no competing definitions among mathematicians with any significant adherence).

Comment: @David K: There are three natural notions of strict increase one can consider -- **(1)** increase on an interval; **(2)** increase at a point; **(3)** local increase at a point. The first two are widely used, and the third is rarely used. The definition of each has nothing to do with derivatives, although there are various theorems that relate these notions with the derivative of a function when the derivative exists. A brief overview of these notions is given in this [16 May 2006 sci.math post archived by google](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/9kU61P-TLOs/m/H7bsXeNAHrkJ).

Comment: @JBL: (alerting you because I can only cite one person per comment, and I've already alerted David K) For more details about the relation between the various types of increase I previously mentioned and having a positive derivative, see this [29 December 2008 sci.math post archived by google](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/OwjFRCdmCqQ/m/-kD760l0LN4J).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro : Of course it is *possible to write down* definitions like those (definitions are for free), but they are exactly the kind of thing I meant when I said referred to definitions without any significant adherence among mathematicians.  The idea of an increasing function is important (and extends easily to more general settings like maps between partial orders); your local versions are not.

Comment: @JBL: *your local versions are not* -- I'm not sure how you come to this conclusion, especially the pointwise version. As I wrote in the second sci.math post I linked, "The idea of monotonicity at a point ... is also used extensively in certain areas of probability and statistics, such as in the analysis of Brownian motion, as well as in the analysis of "fractal like functions", wavelet theory, harmonic analysis, and many other mathematical areas." [example](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nonincrease+everywhere+of+the+Brownian+motion+process%22&filter=0)